# Inter-lambda communication on AWS without polling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Given two distinct lambda functions (A) and (B).

A client calls lambda (A), the call blocks until another client calls Lambda (B) and then returns. [Assuming within 1 minute]

Evidently, Lambda (B) could write a flag to a database, and Lambda (A) could poll on this flag until it's set, and then return. But this approach seems inelegant. Can someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: I would suggest to check [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/application-integration-patterns-for-microservices-orchestration-and-coordination/). [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/category/application-services/aws-step-functions/), you can find useful AWS Step Functions related blogs on AWS.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  You can invoke a Lambda from code synchronously.  Can't Lambda A call Lambda B, wait for the response, and return to the original caller?

Comment: @stdunbar - To give more context, Lambda A calls an external API (not under our control). That system will then use a webhook (not under our control) to call back to Lambda B.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,Lambda is server less/on the go compute. If you trigger a lambda and are polling for something else ,well, that is not what lambda is built for. We have SNS , SQS services which help us in avoiding polling and also help in decoupling +scaling.

May be you try something like this.
1.Let the event (which is triggering lambda A ) post to SQS.
2.Let the Lambda B be triggered.
3.Let Lambda B trigger lambda A and lambda A can get the info/event details from SQS.